# R: placing x ticks under facet panel in ggplot2

Tags: r, layout, ggplot2, facet

In a faceted plot from `ggplot2` package it is possible to change the position of tick marks by the functions like `scale_x_continuous(position="top")`. However, if tick marks are to be placed on top, they appear above faceting panels, as here:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point() + 
facet_grid(. ~ cyl) +coord_flip() +
scale_y_continuous(position="right")
```

[image]

Is it possible to place individual tick marks scales *under* the denotations of facets?

Comment: and the working reproducible example is where?

Comment: you can swap the positions of the strip and axis grobs ; `g =  gplotGrob(p);
indax = grep( "axis-t", g$layout$name) ; indst = grep( "strip-t", g$layout$name) ; ax = g$layout[indax, c("t", "b")] ; st = g$layout[indst, c("t", "b")] ; g$layout[indax, c("t", "b")] <- st ; g$layout[indst, c("t", "b")] <- ax ; grid.newpage() ; grid.draw(g)`

Answer (score 1):

How about pushing the facet panel to the bottom?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(. ~ cyl, switch='x') +coord_flip() +
    scale_y_continuous(position="right")
```

[image]